# MainWindow IBOutlet properties for window, tabBarController log as (null) even though outlets are connected

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication, mainwindow

In my `AppDelegate.h` I have `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window` and `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController`.

In the implementation I `@synthesize *window = _window, *tabBarController = _tabBarController;`.

In my target settings, my `MainWindow.xib` file is specified.

In my `MainWindow.xib` file, I have three objects: `AppDelegate`, `Window`, and `Tab Bar Controller`. I connect `Window` to `AppDelegate`, `Tab Bar Controller` to `Window.rootViewController`, and `Tab Bar Controller` to `AppDelegate`.

Back in `AppDelegate.h`, the outlet circles show as connected.

Finally, in my `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.window);

    return YES;
}
```

The contents of this log are always `(null)`.

On application launch, the window and tab bar controller appear and receive user interaction.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the File's Owner class was set to the `ApplicationDelegate` class rather than `UIApplication`. Setting this to the correct class, then setting the delegate as a delegate of `UIApplication`, totally resolved the issue